# How to adjust div position according to screen size

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, screen-orientation

I have a table in which there is an icon when I hover it the chart appears as a popup

This is my div where chart renders

```
<div id="chart-outer" style="@style" class="popup-chart close">
    <h2 id="charttitle" style="width: 100%; text-align: center;"></h2>
    <div id="chartContainer" style="width: 96%; height: 300px; vertical-align: top; direction: ltr; display: inline-block; padding: 10px;"></div>
</div>
```

On hover on the table icon the chart appear like this

[image: chart on hovering]

As I hover 2nd last item in the table so the chart render on the right side of the icon perfectly fine .

I'm applying css on chart div by javascript like this on hovering icon .

```
   var mouseX = 100, mouseY = 100;
        $(document).mousemove(function (e) {

            mouseX = e.pageX;

            mouseY = e.pageY - 200;
            //console.log(e.pageY);
        });

        //cache the selector
        var follower = $("#chart-outer");
        var xp = 0, yp = 0;
        var loop = setInterval(function () {
            // change 12 to alter damping, higher is slower
            xp += (mouseX - xp) / 1;
            yp += (mouseY - yp) / 1;
         
             xp = '@SharedPageData.CurrentLanguage.LanguageID' == '1' ? 500 : 200;
        
            follower.css({ left: xp, top: yp });

        }, 10);
```

I have 2 versions of pages 1 is for arabic and the 2 is for english so for english I am setting left position to 200 and for arabic I am setting it 500.

It is working fine but on some screens with higher resolution the chart appear on top of the table icon and it starts blinking .

I want to position it on the right side of the icon no matter what the screen size is , and for arabic I want it on the left side of icon .

How can I achieve it

Comment: Rather than calculating different offsets, you should probably position this using either `left` _or_ `right`, depending on the language.

Comment: But the problem is it appears on top og icon when the screen size changes

Comment: Hardly reproducible with what you have shown us so far - proper [mre] of the whole issue, please.

Comment: Plus I can't even currently tell, what exactly the "icons" are supposed to be. A mere screenshot, most of the time, is _not_ an appropriate problem description.

Comment: is it posible to show you

Comment: By just giving us a link, you mean? No - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/1427878

Comment: if you can check it on anydesk

Answer (score 0):

Try using `vw` and `vh`. This is a CSS unit relative of the window size, example:

- `10vw` means `10%` of the total window width
- `30vh` means `30%` of the total window height.

So you can try:

```css
.popup-chart {
  width: 30vw;
  height: 10vh;
}
```